# Trying to create an on time update function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm using Joomla to create a website, this website will have a section where some track previews will be available. Until now I've managed to create the elements and play each one individually. But now I'm trying to create a function that will increase the width of a Div depending on the playing position, due to the dynamic creation on the PHP, I need to create a dynamic function to enlarge this div, here's what I have that doesn't work.

```
<audio preload="metadata" id="<?php echo $videoid; ?>" class="preview play" ontimeupdate='updateTrackTime(this);'>
        <source src="<?php echo $video; ?>" type="audio/mp3"/>
</audio>
<div class="player play">
    <div id="<?php echo $videoid; ?>play" class="chargebar"></div>
</div>
```

This is the php that creates the player
Then I've created a small function outside the `jQuery(document).ready(` function.

```
function updateTrackTime(track){
    var perc = Math.floor((track.currentTime/track.duration)*100).toString()+'%';
    var currTime = perc;
    var trackid = jQuery(event.target).attr('id');
    trackid = trackid+'play';
    var currDiv = jQuery(trackid);
    perc = 'width : '+perc;
    if (currTime == '2%'){
        alert(trackid);
        alert(currDiv.attr('id'));
    }
}
```

As you can see I was trying to debug the thing to understand what's happening.
The `trackid` answers correctly (exemple: HVOHfDJSOBRM), but when I ask for the confirmation that he found the right "chargebar" Div (`currDiv`) the answer is `undifined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you forgot to add a `#` to your argument to `jQuery`, indicating that you want to select an element with ID `trackid`. [More information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ID_selectors).

Change

```
var currDiv = jQuery(trackid);
```

to

```
var currDiv = jQuery('#' + trackid);
```

That should fix it.

On another note: you use `var trackid = jQuery(event.target).attr('id');` while variable `event` is not defined anywhere (at least not in the code you are showing here). Apparently it works for you, but I suggest you change that to `var trackid = track.id;`, which simply reads the ID attribute from the track on which the time update was triggered.